# Can not use native code: Initialisation failed. Cannot create Excel Object

Tags: java, excel, coldfusion, com, coldfusion-8

I am trying to convert excel file to .csv file using ColdFusion code. I have written the following code. While I am trying to create excel COM object in server i am getting a java runtime exception like

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not use native code: Initialisation failed. Cannot create Excel Object"
```

I am using ColdFusion 8.0. Please help me to solve this exception.

Code:

```
<!---Converting Excel file to CSV file--->
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="Yes">

<!--------------------------------------------------------- Constants ---->

<!------------------------------------------------ Initial Parameters ---->
<cfparam name="sheetName" type="string" default="sheet1">
<cfparam name="showConfirmation" type="boolean" default="0">

<!--- Try to connect to the Word application object --->
<cftry>
  <!--- If it exists, connect to it --->
  <cfobject 
           action="CONNECT" 
           class="Excel.Application" 
           name="objExcel" 
           type="COM">
  <cfcatch type="ANY">
    <!--- The object doesn't exist, so create it --->
    <cftry>
      <cfobject 
               action="CREATE" 
               class="Excel.Application" 
               name="objExcel" 
               type="COM"> 
      <!--- Word isn't installed, or ColdFusion doesn't have access to it --->
      <cfcatch type="ANY">
        <cfoutput>
          <cfdump var="#cfcatch.Detail#">
          <font size="-1"><b>Cannot create Excel Object</b><br>
            <ol>
              <li>Make sure Excel is installed on the ColdFusion Server.</li>
              <li>Make sure that ColdFusion has permissions to 
                                   use the Excel COM objects.</li>
            </ol>
          </font>
        </cfoutput>
        <cfabort>
      </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
<cftry>
  <cfscript>
    // this code will open up the excel spread sheet and then save it as a CSV file.

    // Excel file path
    ExcelFilePath = "#path#csar_reports\Budgeting_Requests_as of_#date#.xls";

    // Destination path for new Excel spreadsheet
    // We leave off the extension since we'll declare the file type later on
    CSVFilePath = "#path#csar_reports\Budgeting_Requests_as of_#date#.csv";

    // Open Excel in the background
    objExcel.Visible = false;  

    // Disable alerts such as: 'Save this document?'
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;               

    // Get the 'Documents' collection
    objBooks = objExcel.workbooks;  

    // Open the Excel spreadsheet
    objBook = objBooks.Open(ExcelFilePath);  

    // Get the sheets collection 
    objSheets = objBook.WorkSheets;

    // Get the first sheet 
    objSheet = objSheets.Item(Val(1));   

    // Get a named sheet 
    //objSheet = objSheets.Item("#sheetName#");       


    /* Save it as a new document -- the extension will automatically
       be appended based on the file type we choose.
       Some of the file types to convert to:
       1 = .xls
       3 = .txt (tab delimetered)
       6 = .csv
    */
    objSheet.SaveAs(CSVFilePath, Val(6));  

    // Close the spreadsheet
    objBook.Close();     

    // Quit Excel
    objExcel.Quit();

    if (showConfirmation EQ 1) {
      writeOutput("<font size=""-1"" face=""Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif""><b>File Created:</b> ""#attributes.CSVFileOut#"" <b>from file:</b> ""#attributes.excelFileIn#""<p></font>");
    }
  </cfscript>

  <cfcatch>
    <!--- error creating file --->
    <cfoutput>
      <font face="Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" size="-1">there was an error creating your 
                     new CSV filesfrom your Excel Spreadsheet
      <P>#cfcatch.message#</P> <P>Caught an exception, type = #cfcatch.type# </P> <P>The contents of the tag stack are:</P> <cfloop index = i from = 1 to = #ArrayLen(cfcatch.tagContext)#> <cfset sCurrent = #cfcatch.tagContext[i]#> <BR>#i# #sCurrent["ID"]# (#sCurrent["LINE"]#,#sCurrent["COLUMN"]#) #sCurrent["TEMPLATE"]# </cfloop> 
    </cfoutput>
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="no">
```

Comment: Sandeep - what have you done to troubleshoot? Why do you believe the error you are getting is _incorrect_. Is the proper Excel COM dll installed on the server?

Comment: @Mark- I have no idea why the exception is occurring. I have checked in server, MS excel is installed.

Comment: Where did you get this code? What version of Excel is installed? Old versions use COM, newer versions .NET. There are lots of dependencies here Sandeep. It will take a lot of trial and error to make this happen.

Comment: @SandeepReddyK. What is your server configuration?